# Как убрать стрелочки c input date?

Tags: дата, input

При наведении появляются стрелки вверх-вниз, стрелка для раскрытия календаря и кнопка Х (очистить). Как убрать все эти дефолтные стрелки?

Comment: Решение зависит от платформы/языка/ui-фреймворка/т.п.. Опишите вопрос детальнее.

Comment: К сожалению, не смог убрать крестик, видимо, которую Вы назвали кнопка X (очистить). Напишите, если у вас получилось.

Comment: К счастью нашёл, либо 
input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button { display: none; }, но это работает только в webkit.
Элегантнее добавить в тег атрибут requiter <input type="date" value="2012-12-12" required>

Answer (score 1):

> https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#input_date

все псевдоклассы , которые можно убрать , с помощью можно убрать все что угодно

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field
::-webkit-inner-spin-button
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator
```

Comment: спасибо большое